# PostgreSQL -- put everything into one table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

So I'm trying to learn some basic database design principles and decided to download a copy of the sr27 database provided by the [USDA](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=24912).  The database is storing nutritional information on food, and statistical information on how these nutritional values were derived.

When I first started this project, my thoughts were: well, I want to be able to search for food names, and I will probably want to do some basic statistical modeling on your most common nutritional values like calories, proteins, fats, etc.  So, the thought was simple, just make 3 tables that look like this:

- One table for food names
- One table for common nutritional values (1-1 relationship with names)
- One table for other nutritional values (1-1 relationship with names)

However, it's not clear that this is even necessary.  Do you gain anything from partitioning the columns (or values) based on the idea:  I like to do searches on names, so let's keep that as one table for less overhead, and I like to data calculations on common nutritional values so let's keep that as another table.  (**Question 1**) Or does proper indexing make this moot?

My next question is then:  Why in the world did the USDA decide to use 12 tables?  Is this considered good database design practice, or would they have been better off merging a lot of these tables? (this excerpt is taken from the PDF provided in the USDA link above, pg 29)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Do you gain anything from partitioning the columns (or values) based
>   on the idea: I like to do searches on names, so let's keep that as one
>   table for less overhead, and I like to data calculations on common
>   nutritional values so let's keep that as another table. (Question 1)
>   Or does proper indexing make this moot?

if you just had a list of items, and you want to summarize on just some of them, then indexing is the way to address performance, not splitting some into another table arbitrarily.

Also, do read up on Normalization.

> My next question is then: Why in the world did the USDA decide to use
>   12 tables? Is this considered good database design practice, or would
>   they have been better off merging a lot of these tables? (this excerpt
>   is taken from the PDF provided in the USDA link above, pg 29)

Probably because the types of questions they want to ask are not exactly the same ones you are trying to ask.

They clearly have more info about each food - like groups, nutrients, weights, and they are also apparently tracking where the source data is coming from...

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I read the Wiki on DB Normalization. It appears that my scheme was biased with to particular queries, which should be avoided.  So to apply these practices, while constructing a logical scheme, I should basically take any entity (name, group, nutrition, statistics, etc..) pretend I need to modify it and look for possible anomalies.  For instance, putting food group with name would have a group rename potential anomaly.  Basically I'm learning that I should just separate logical design and physical design?

Comment: well for sure logical does not equal physical.  but it is more than that, you need each row to basically represent one and only one fact or truth, then you an link a bunch of those up with other rows for meaningful information.  This part takes practice, and you can study some rules for how this can be achieved to the various 'normal forms'

Answer (score 0):

There are important rules related to design relational databases - [Normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) - that reduces some artefacts and reduce IO operations. This design is usual for OLTP databases - and I have a possibility to see terrible slow databases because the developers has zero knowledge about it. Analytical databases OLAP are little bit different - there are wide tables used and some modern OLAP databases with column store support it.

PostgreSQL is classic row store database - so all in one table is not common and it is not good strategy. You can use a `view` to create some typical and often used views on data - so the complex schema can be invisible (transparent) for you.

Comment: I see. (We are pretending my food database is massive).  So if I had two uses for my data: one for searching and modifying, and one for big data anaysis, then I might be better off having two different databases for this?  I'm just trying to make sure that I am understanding your response :)

Comment: It depends on a size of databases - for small project analytic databases are not necessary - for some large data (more than 100GB) - the special databases with data optimized for analytic is usual.